# How can I force the symfony entity-manager to recognize existing sub-entities?

Tags: rest, symfony, symfony-2.8

I'm using Fos_rest to do a webservice.
I recive an entity from an Angular App in JSON.
JSON example :

```
{"model":
   {
    "trademark":
      {"id":1,"name":"Alfa Romeo"},
    "type":
      {"id":1,"code":"car","name":"Car"},
    "name":"147"
    }
}
```

The entity is composed of two sub entities, called "trademark" and "type".

When receiving a POST, in controller does the following:

```
public function cpostAction(Request $request, $idTrademark)
   {
        $entity = new Model();
        $form = $this->createForm(ModeloType::class, $entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);  
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $entity = $form->getData();
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            /*do things with the entity and return*/
        }
   }
```

The problem is given when doing Flush, since it recognizes "trademark" and "type" as new entities, since these already exist when owning an "id".
How can I force the entity manager to recognize the entities "trademark" and "type" from the database?

P.S:
Form Type:

```
class ModelType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name')
                ->add('trademark', TrademarkType::class)
                ->add('type', TypeType::class)
                ->add('id');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Model',
            'csrf_protection' => false,
            'allow_extra_fields' => true,
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved it by adding the following lines before the "Persist":
$entity->setTrademark($em->find(Trademark::class, $entity->getTrademark()->getId()));
$entity->setType($em->find(Type::class, $entity->getType()->getId()));

Comment: You should not do a find : it does a database request. Prefer `$em->getReference(Type::class, $entity->getType()->getId())`

Comment: That's just what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! I post it as an answer, see ya!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not do a `find()` : it does a database request. Prefer:

```
$em->getReference(Type::class, $entity->getType()->getId())
```

It does not a database query. The only problem is `getReference` does not check if the entity is still existing in the database. For me `getReference` should only be used to transform an id to the doctrine proxy object

Comment: There is no problem, since doing `$em->persist($ entity); $em->flush();` If entities do not exist throw an exception. Thanks for the reply!